# Bot framework to work with LUIS intent & match intent & pro-active dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I've built a bot using LUIS framework which works fine.
while working on it came through few points as mentioned below

1. After connecting with LUIS intent; bot is unable to check with regex intents
   like

   **for ex dialog.matches('^helpdesk/i',function())** which i'm trying to setup

`var dialog = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });`

1. How to proactively send greetings message to user before inititates conversation like i would send prompt of choices to user which user can select. If nothing is fitting to that requirement  i want LUIS to work and understand on that
2. How to know the logged in user context in **Skype for Business** channel
3. cards are not working in skype for business

Answer (score 0):

For your code; I'm assuming your `recognizer` is your only IntentRecognizer and is the LUIS model you mention.

In this case, `dialog.matches('^helpdesk/i',function())` is incorrect; your code to match against a regex should be `dialog.matches(/^helpdesk/i, function())`

Alternatively you could add a [`RegExpRecognizer`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/dialogs/RegExpRecognizer.js) to your IntentDialog:

```
var helpdesk = new builder.RegExpRecognizer('HelpDeskIntent', /^helpdesk/i);
var dialog = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [helpdesk, recognizer] });
```

1. As Bob said you're looking for [conversationUpdate](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.iconversationupdate.html), here's an [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/snippets/basics-greetingUsers-conversationUpdate.js) on it sending a message when a user joins
2. To clarify, is this a question on having your bot know when a user is logged in? Or are you asking about session.userData?
3. Skype for Business does not currently support cards.

Comment: Thanks @Steven G. 
in a scenario where I would to like to have /helpdesk, /itsupport, /hrhelpdesk do i need to end-up with multiple recognizers?
What if we could make use of dialog.matches() for multilple dialogs

Comment: You can end up with multiple recognizers, but you can also call these dialogs by using [`triggerAction()`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.intentdialog.html#triggeraction). Depending on how you set up your dialogs, you can arrange it so that via `triggerAction()` you can access these help dialogs anytime. I don't think you could use dialog.matches() in the way you may be thinking of, but I may be off the mark; do you have an example? e.g. are you talking about `matches(/^(helpdesk|hrhelpdesk)/i)`  I don't think you're asking for this...?

Answer (score -1):

1. You can catch when the user is added to conversation. Check [conversation.update.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-activities)
2. Each activity has its own properties. One of them is [serviceUrl](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/d2f/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_activity.html#ad151704b4dbe85c03ba3e52fa61004ad).

For the third question, please provide your code.